# how to use ruby " case ... when " with inequalities?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

can you do this in ruby?
it seems to "miss" the cases with inequalities

```
 case myvar
 when  myvar < -5
    do somethingA
 when -5..-3
    do special_something_XX
 when -2..-1
    do special_something_YY
 when myvar == 0
    do somethingB
 when myvar > 0
    go somethingC
 end
```

Comment: You can use regex to catch the different cases instead

Comment: @Flexo: Would your approach handle scientific notation?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You are mixing two different types of case statements:

```
case var
when 1
  dosomething
when 2..3
  doSomethingElse
end

case
when var == 1
   doSomething
when var < 12
   doSomethingElse
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful to me, a relative newbie!

Comment: wow, all this time i didn't realize the 2nd type existed.  thanks.

Comment: eli5 written all over it! My favourite kind of explanations :)

Answer (score 27):

```
   case myvar
     when  proc { |n| n < -5 }
        do somethingA
     when -5..-3
        do special_something_XX
     when -2..-1
        do special_something_YY
     when proc { |n| n == 0 }
        do somethingB
     when proc { |n| n > 0 }
        go somethingC
     end
   end
```

Comment: A few explanations and link would have been nice.

Answer (score 9):

I am not personally convinced that you wouldn't be better off with if statements, but if you want a solution in that form:

```
Inf = 1.0/0

case myvar
when -Inf..-5
  do somethingA
when -5..-3
  do special_something_XX
when -2..-1
  do special_something_YY
when 0
  do somethingB
when 0..Inf
  do somethingC
end
```

My preferred solution follows. Here the order matters and you have to repeat the `myvar`, but it's much harder to leave out cases, you don't have to repeat each bound twice, and the strictness (`<` vs `<=` rather than `..` vs `...`) is much more obvious.

```
if myvar <= -5
  # less than -5
elsif myvar <= -3
  # between -5 and -3
elsif myvar <= -1
  # between -3 and -1
elsif myvar <= 0
  # between -1 and 0
else
  # larger than 0
end
```

Comment: I personally think that what makes the second alternative clearer are the comments, not the fact that if-elsif is used instead of case-when. That said, I also prefer if-elsif, but just because it is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

```
def project_completion(percent)
 case percent
  when  percent..25
    "danger"
  when percent..50
    "warning"
  when percent..75
    "info"
  when percent..100
    "success"
  else
   "info"
  end
end
```

Comment: This way seems kind of hackish, and presumably leads to `percent` being compared against itself several times.  `case` / `when percent <= 25` / ... seems better (less code/more efficient).  It's not necessarily quite as clear that `percent` is the focus of the comparisons, but I think it's easy to see that by looking at the `when` expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Using [infinity](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#INFINITY) may help

```
case var
when -Float::INFINITY..-1
when 0
when 1..2
when 3..Float::INFINITY
end
```