# Implementing the 'case' statement in order to match multiple 'when' conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to use a `case` statement that even after matching a `when` statement can continue to checks other `when statement` until the last `else`.

For example

```
case var
when '1'
  if var2 == ...
    ...
  else
    ...
    puts "Don't make nothig but continue to check!"
    # Here I would like to continue to check if a 'when' statement will match 'var' until the 'else' case
  end
when '2'
  ...
...
else
  put "Yeee!"
```

end

**Is it possible in Ruby? If so, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have any sort of fall-through for `case`.

One alternative be a series of `if` statements using the `===` method, which is what `case` uses internally to compare the items.

```
has_matched? = false

if '2' === var
  has_matched? = true
  # stuff
end

if '3' === var
  has_matched? = true
  # other stuff
end

if something_else === var
  has_matched? = true
  # presumably some even more exciting stuff
end

if !has_matched?
  # more stuff
end
```

This has two glaring issues.

1. It isn't very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): `has_matched? = true` is littered all over the place.
2. You always need to remember to place `var` on the right-hand-side of `===`, because that's what `case` does behind the scenes.

You could create your own class with a `matches?` method that encapsulates this functionality. It could have a constructor that takes the value you'll be matching against (in this case, `var`), and it could have an `else_do` method that only executes its block if its internal `@has_matched?` instance variable is still false.

**Edit:**

The `===` method can mean anything you want it to mean. Generally, it's a more "forgiving" way to test *equivalency* between two objects. Here's an example from this [this page](http://www.pmamediagroup.com/2009/07/dont-call-it-case-equality/):

```
class String
  def ===(other_str)
    self.strip[0, other_str.length].downcase == other_str.downcase
  end
end

class Array
  def ===(str)
    self.any? {|elem| elem.include?(str)}
  end
end

class Fixnum
  def ===(str)
    self == str.to_i
  end
end
```

Essentially, when Ruby encounters `case var`, it will call `===` on the objects *against which* you are comparing `var`.

Comment: Ruby has a fall-through for case.  It's 'else'.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the code  I see coming from ruby is done with `if elsif else` but you can mimic switch logical expressions similar to other languages like this:

```
case var
when 1
  dosomething
when 2..3
  doSomethingElse
end

case
when var == 1
   doSomething
when var < 12
   doSomethingElse
end
```

This came from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114584/how-to-use-ruby-case-when-with-inequalities). Like I said this is usually done with `if elsif else` in ruby such as:

```
if my_number == "1"
   #do stuff when equals 1
elsif my_number == "e"
   #same thing here
else
   #default, no case found
end
```